# On hover show image for textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a simple textbox, and I would like to show an image if user hovers mouse over the textbox.
So at the moment I have

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" id="BitRate" name="BitRate" value="13000">
```

And I want to do it, so that if user hovers over this textbox it will display
image.png that is in same directory as the file where this textbox is.

Also if someone can point me to some nice jquery tutorials I would be really grateful. I have been doing my own projects for fun trying to learn jquery, but so far I only managed to look up code online, use it, get it to work, and have no idea at all why it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/c5ZKN/

**API reference**
http://api.jquery.com/hide/
http://api.jquery.com/show/

**Sample tutorial**
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

```
// hide the image initially
$('#my_img').hide();

$(".textbox").hover(
    // show
    function(){
        $('#my_img').show();
    },
    // hide
    function() {
        $('#my_img').hide();    
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect, and the tutorial along with jsfiddle is very good. Thank you!!!